# Is it possible to display Facebook users timeline on website?

Tags: php, facebook, json

**OBJECTIVE:** I need to display latest 5 entries from users timeline on website, using PHP.
Please not that i speak about timeline of user profile - not fan page, not group.

**SO FAR I DID THIS:**

1. Registered as Facebook developer
2. Registered app
3. Obtained token
4. Opened url: https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=MY_TOKEN
5. Voila. Feed of that user is displayed now, **but..**

**PROBLEM:** So now i have users feed, but it looks like its partially working. 
It happens often that it don't displays some updates, sometimes it displays just date of the post and not the content.

However when i try to grab feed from some facebook fan page, then everything work normal.

**MY QUESTION:** Are we allowed to grab user timeline? If yes, what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't ever see all the information that is visible inside the Facebook app via the api. This comes from how Facebook filters out the data. See this Facebook Developers blog post for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: Okay, but is it possible to overcome this?

Comment: No. You have to take what Facebook gives you and be happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are allowed to to grab user timeline posts, even with a limit, if your app asks for read_stream permission. Issue an HTTP GET request to the below URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/posts?access_token=token&limit=5
```

Comment: Still same. Just with your url i have different posts that are not even visible on the user timeline.. I have tried with my profile, profile of my friend and im facing same issues: that information which i get from opengraph are very very different from informations currently displayed on the user timeline.

Comment: Well, this is how I do it :)